# Trying to assign vector of Base* from vector of Derived*

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, vector

This seems like a pretty basic problem, but I can't figure it out.  I have a `std::vector` of raw pointers to Derived objects, and I just want to copy it to another vector of Base pointers using the assignment operator.  With VC++ I get error C2679 "binary '=': no operator found..."  BTW I don't want a deep copy of the objects, I just want to copy the pointers.  Sample code:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Base{};    
struct Derived: public Base {};

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    vector<Derived*> V1;
    vector<Base*> V2;
    V2 = V1;  //Compiler error here
    return 0;
}
```

What confuses me is that I can copy the vector by looping through it and using `push_back`, like this:

```
for (Derived* p_derived : V1)
    V2.push_back(p_derived);
```

So my question is why does the assignment fail, while `push_back` works?  Seems like the same thing to me.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That's because while `Base` and `Derived` have a relationship, there is no relationship between `vector<Base*>` and `vector<Derived*>`. As far as class hierarchy is concerned, they are entirely unrelated, so you can't assign one to the other.

The concept you are looking for is called [**covariance**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)). In Java for instance, `String[]` is a subtype of `Object[]`. But in C++, these two types are just different types and are no more related than `String[]` and `Bar`.

`push_back` works because that method just takes a `T const&` (or `T&&`), so anything convertible to a `Base*` will be acceptable - which a `Derived*` is.

That said, `vector` has a constructor that takes a pair of iterators, which should be easier to use here:

```
vector<Base*> v2(v1.begin(), v1.end());
```

Or, since it is already constructed:

```
v2.assign(v1.begin(), v1.end());
```

Comment: I suppose the assignment operator would become overly complicated if it had to accept vectors of different-but-related types.

Comment: This is a (pretty common) C++ FAQ as well. See [this](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/containers#container-ptr-conversion).

Comment: In C# `List<Base>` is also unrelated to `List<Derived>` but `IEnumerable<Base>` is a subtype of `IEnumerable<Derived>` because `IEnumerable` is variant.

Comment: @usr *co*variant. To go along with the FAQ example, that doesn't violate type safety because `IEnumerable<T>` is a read-only interface, so you can't break the `vector<Apple*>`. However, one could imagine in a system such that that `vector<T>` is still invariant but there existed a `const_vector<T>`, which could be covariant.

Answer (score 9):

`push_back` performs element-wise conversions. The assignment operator exists only between vectors of the same type.

An easy solution is to use `assign`:

```
v2.assign(v1.begin(), v1.end());
```

Answer (score 2):

In the general case of templates, if you have a class template

```
template <typename T> struct Foo {};
```

`Foo<Base>` is not a base class of `Foo<Derived>`.

Hence, you cannot do:

```
Foo<Derived> f1;
Foo<Base> f2 = f1;
```